# Issue with displaying a long cell(like a rectangle) in a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to display a collection view image which looks like so...

[image]

Here, as you can see the whole cell is of a rectangle shape with space for text and buttons below the image. I am not able to load such a 'rectangle' shaped cell in my collectioview. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: what you get result?

Comment: What have you tried? please show the code

Comment: I have loaded the collection view with the image but the image is appearing square shaped instead of rectangle shape. If I remove the leading, trailing constraints and give the constraints like height, width,center horizontally, center vertically, then the image becomes rectangle but each image is separated from the other by more space than is required while they should be close to each other..

Comment: implement the method of "sizeforitem" you can define the width and height of cell

Answer (score 1):

To set the size of item of a collectionview you can implement this `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 30, height: 100)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear as it does not show your code or what result  you got. But it is quiet simple 
For customising cell size use below code and pass width and height accordingly

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: accordingly to your requirement, height: accordingly to your requirement)
```

}

Please check this link which can explain every bit in detail. And play with different value to get your required result.

[Custom cell collectionview](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link, @cole. Actually, I figured the issue...While setting up the collection view in viewDidLoad, I had specified the width and height in layout.itemsize as width/2 and width/2. This was causing the issue...The height factor shouldn't have been divided by 2.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. FYI in future paste your code or result you are getting to get better help and answer